# icu_date gives an error message attempt to index a number value

Tags: lua, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I want to use the icu_date library, but when I try to insert a value, an error appears

```lua
icu_date = require("icu-date")
format_date = icu_date.formats.iso8601()
end_time = icu_date.now()
```

```
1602586287098 - print value
end_time:set_millis(1602461532000)
error: '[string "return end_time:set_millis(1602461532000)"]:1: attempt to index global ''end_time'' (a number value)'
```

Maybe there are not enough libraries?

- Library libicu-devel-50.2-4.el7_7.x86_64
- System: Centos 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to use `icu_date.new()` (not `now`) to create new instance. Then you can use it in the way you want:

```lua
icu_date = require("icu-date")
format_date = icu_date.formats.iso8601()
end_time = icu_date.new()
end_time:set_millis(1602461532000)
tarantool> end_time:format(format_date)
---
- 2020-10-12T00:12:12.000Z
...
```

`icu_date.now()` returns current time. That's actually a number value.

```lua
tarantool> icu_date = require('icu-date')
---
...

tarantool> icu_date.now()
---
- 1602597687320
...
```

Comment: Oleg, I do as you wrote, an error appears: .rocks/share/tarantool/icu-date/init.lua:17: tarantool init.lua:  undefined symbol: udat_formatCalendar_50'

Comment: Seems you use too old version of icu-date. I suggest you to update libicu and file an issue (https://github.com/tarantool/icu-date/issues), I think it's possible to fix compatibility with older versions.